# Cannot find module '@angular/core/src/render3'

Tags: angular

I have some trouble after updating from angular 7 to 8.

```
 ng --version

Angular CLI: 8.3.22
Node: 10.18.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.22
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.22
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.22
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.22
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.22
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.22
@angular/cdk                      8.0.2
@angular/cli                      8.3.22
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                 8.0.2
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.22
@schematics/angular               8.3.22
@schematics/update                0.803.22
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.39.2
```

So this is my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "~8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.8.3",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001020",
    "chromedriver": "^79.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "~2.6.11",
    ...
    "material-design-icons": "~3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "~1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.22",
      ...
  },
```

Nothing special in it.
When I try to build my project I get `Cannot find module '@angular/core/src/render3'` and yes:

```
ls node_modules/@angular/core/src/
core.externs.js  r3_symbols.d.ts  testability
```

What is render3? I bet there is again some version mismatch of the dependencies, but I can't figure it out this time.

Comment: Check where the module `@angular/core/src/render3` is imported in your code

Comment: It's imported i a class with `import { pipe } from '@angular/core/src/render3';``But this module should still exist in angular8 - https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/8.2.12/packages/core/src/render3

Comment: shouldnt this be "`import { pipe } from '@angular/core`"

Comment: I am not sure, in '@angular/core' there ist only `Pipe` (Uppercase)... but I found that this dependency isn't used at all, so it must be relic leftover by a bad programmer >.< I did not even consider such thing. sorry for your time.

Comment: @Paflow if you see the docs (the API) you see in witch module there are the Pipe https://v8.angular.io/api/core/Pipe -see at top, you see `API>@angular/core`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```js
import { ******* } from "@angular/core";
```

instead of

```js
import { ******* } from "@angular/core/src/render3";
```

Comment: You are a wise man.